# Is it possible to add a Sitecore Form in an iframe?

Tags: sitecore-forms

We want to reference a page from Sitecore with a Sitecore Forms form inside it to an external site. However, when I did so. I encountered xxx things:

1. The iframe threw an error regarding the `X-Frame-Options`

   - To fix this, I added the `frame-ancestors 'self' https://external.site` in the header
2. Once this was resolved, every time I blur from the field it shows an alert popup saying `Your session has expired. Please refresh the page`
3. When I tried submitting the form, the form failed to submit. Upon checking, I discovered that the form submit returned a `Message: The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.` message.

So the question is: is it really possible to reference a Sitecore Form in an iframe? If yes, which area of the environment should I look for in order to resolve the issues #2, #3 above?

Comment: Are you abe to make it work.

Comment: @SitecoreKumar I did! I added my answer. Feel free to comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue! The problem lies on the `SameSite` cookie property of `ASP.NET_SessionId` and `__RequestVerificationToken`. By default, it was set to `Lax`. So, I created a pipeline that would change these cookies’ `SameSite` property to `None` and that resolved the issue.

Be sure that your .NET Framework version is 4.7.2 and later.

Reference:
https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an ideal case for using Embeddable Forms Framework (EEF) that ships with Sitecore 10.3 when using forms with external sites.

#2 and #3 are closely related to CSRF, brief details are here by Mark [Forms message - Your session has expired](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31217/forms-message-your-session-has-expired-please-refresh-this-page).

You can try out the below step for #3.

1. This could be because of caching. Can you check if your rendering
   component or container/page level caching check box is checked? if
   so, unchecking the caching will fix the issue.
2. Also here is a quick check you can do to see whether your form is cached – Inspect the form and check the _requestverificationtoken value like below and refresh the page – do you see the same value now? if so, your form is in the cache!
3. Bypassing Sitecore’s Request Verification [Link](https://sitecorehacker.com/2017/11/10/bypassing-sitecores-request-verification/).

Hope it helps!